# sed question on how to add a # to beginning of a pattern match

Tags: sed

How do you add a comment in front of this line with sed?

I'm trying to add a # sign to line in front of this but my sed is not working.

When I attempt to there is no match.

auth           required        pam_wheel.so use_uid

```
sed -i 's/auth           required        pam_wheel.so use_ui/#auth           required        pam_wheel.so use_ui/g' /etc/pam.d/su but it is not matching.
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -i.bak '/pam_wheel.so use_ui$/s/^/#/' /etc/pam.d/su
```

`-i.bak` will create a backup of the file with `.bak` extension (or anything you wish to name it).